# Problem on Differentiation Under Integral Sign on Wikipedia page

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

There is a question on the wikipedia page: [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Example_5)
in which the method Differentiation under integral sign is used. In the ending it is written that

> However, by definition, I(π/2) = 0

But there is no mention of such thing there, am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Look at the integral's limits and plug into formula

Comment: Look at the definition of $I(\alpha)$. What is $\ln(1+\cos(\alpha)\cos(x))$ when $\alpha=\pi/2$?

Comment: Thats the way to do it, with Leibniz trick ...annulating the integral to evaluate the constant K taking $\alpha = \frac \pi 2 $ or $ \alpha=\frac {-\pi} 2$

Comment: @MathLover $\color{teal}{zero}$

Comment: $$I(\pi/2)=C-(\pi)^2/8 \iff C=(\pi)^2/8 $$

Comment: @Isham got it , Thanks! but why did we plug $\pi /2$ in $I(\alpha)$?

Comment: to get the value of the constant

Comment: @Isham is it to get the value of $\alpha$ where $I(\alpha)$ becomes $zero$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we can plug that into the formula for $I(\alpha)$ to get $I(\frac{\pi}{2})=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln(1)}{\cos x}\;dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}0\;dx =0$